# How to Export an Excel data set to a Sharepoint Access 2010 list?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a Sharepoint 2010 Access list which already had some data populated in it. I get data from my client in an Excel which then is needed to be appended to that Sharepoint Access list. Is there an easy way to do this? Can I bulk upload this new data which would automatically get appended on Sharepoint.

Comment: You could just delete your current list and then use "Import Spreadsheet" to upload all of the new data... but that's only if you still have the old data in your excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export your existing list to Excel.

Combine the two Excel spreadsheets into one.

Import the final Excel spreadsheet to SharePoint (http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/import-a-spreadsheet-as-a-list-in-sharepoint-2010.html)